# ASP .NET MVC - How to redirect a user control to the view its called from?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a user control that creates a new record in a database. After it creates the new record, I would like to redirect it back to the view its from. The purpose of this is to refresh the view so that it can show the newly created record. The problem is that user control can exists in more than one view, so how can i know which view is the user control from? so that I can achieve the above scenario? Thanks,

RWendi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a user control that creates a new record in a database.

No, it doesn't. It just renders HTML, and nothing else.

It's the controller action which creates a new record in the database, and thus this is where the redirect should happen.

The **[HttpPost] action** which accepts the model/form should perform the redirect after the save has been completed.

E.g:

```
public ActionResult Save(SomeModel model)
{
   db.Save(model);
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I'm assuming that the "view" you want to refresh is the same page, regardless of which page the user controller was rendered on, therefore the above code is fine.

On a side note, you shouldn't be using user controls (e.g partials) for rendering forms.

You should be using **editor templates**. The presentation code which renders the form (and specifies which action to post to) should be in the view, not in the user control.

**EDIT - example of how to render form on Views:**

Instead of doing this on a View:

```
@Html.Partial("_SomeModel")
```

Do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeModel)
}
```

And place the form markup in the editor template. The key thing here is IMO the Views should be responsible for setting up the form, not the user control.

Comment: As I mentioned, this form may be placed in more than 1 view. Wouldn't it be a bad programming practice to not implement it in a user control (partial view)? If I put this form in 5 views, without using user control, whenever I make changes, I have to do it in 5 different places. Hence the usage of user control/Partial view.

Comment: @RWendi - see my edit. You only need to put the `Html.BeginForm` declaration on each view. The markup for the actual form is placed in the editor template (1 place). IMO opinions, Views should be setting up the form, not user controls.

Comment: Are you saying if I want a form in two different views (for example main index view and product index view), I have to setup two forms for each view (one form in main index view, and another one in product index view)? EditorTemplates have to be placed in the root of both folders as well. If i want to make changes to the looks of the form I need to do it in both places too. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @RWendi - are you using areas? If so, and your views are in 2 different areas, then put the editor template in the root /Shared/EditorTemplates folder, and you only have to change one place. So yes, your missing something. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways,

1) You can use `this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` , which will always give you the Url of your page.

2) Or, you can have a hidden property in ... in PartialView, which will hold the value for current url. (`@this.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`) 
But only if you are using @Html.RenderAction.

In the child action, you can redirect to either of above urls. (First approach is much more better and will work in all scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

I think the refresh is responsibility of the action that renders the view your user control is from.

You can have scenarios (or views) where the inserting is done in one action and then pass the request to another action (maybe a list) that shows the newly created record.

Or you can have other scenarios where the inserting is just part of what you want to save to the db and refreshing the original view may cause the loss of data.

Maybe what I'm saying is not what happens with your project right now but it's something you should consider before giving the user control a responsibility it shouldn't have.